# How to not open msn.com on login

Tags: windows-10

For some reason msn.com keeps opening in Edge every time user signs in. Chrome is the default browser and new tab page of Edge is not msn.com. Seems that something keeps opening msn.com deliberately and with Edge specifically. However, the users startup folder is empty. Nor does edge seem to be listed in other autostart listings. The computer has F-Secure virus protection.

I used the [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) util provided by Microsoft to try to figure out what opens the page but this does not seem to help since svchost.exe and some other similar processes are always shown as the parent of Edge.

There user account has no password and the problem does not happen when the computer is rebooted. Only when the user locks the computer (windows+l) and signs in by clicking on "sign in" button.  Multiple tabs with msn.com appear if the user visits the lock screen several times. A new tab is opened everytime user clicks on the sign in button.

Comment: I would check for virus/malware. If it is a company machine (with customized Windows, like the ones big techs use), there might be an IT tool that is doing that - to check that, you will need to contact the IT department.

Comment: The computer does have virus protection. I added that to the description.

Comment: Since you are already using process explorer.. take a quick look at [Autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns).  You can see every single thing in startup and deselect it.  It shows EVERYTHING including even shell extensions.  I would run MalwareBytes against it first (can't hurt).. then if the problem remains, run Autoruns and see what is getting loaded.  I am guessing that because the website is msn.com, it isn't malware.  Why would malware do that??

Comment: If Edge comes up even if Chrome is the default browser it might be related to the Windows spotlight (the picture background and the there's text boxes shown on the login screen). One of the boxes allows you to click on it and after login edge opened and performs a bing search for the topic of the shown picture. I would suspect that for an unknown reason only Edge open works but the search is not executed.